# d3.jsを利用してはてなブックマークの新着記事を表示したい

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors

現在[こちらのページ](http://qiita.com/tag1216/items/ad406625dc654d3c0982)のtag1216様のプログラムを参考にはてなブックマークの新着記事のタグを収集し、同じようにForceレイアウトで表示し、ノードに記事へのリンクをつけたいと考えています。

しかしはてな[ブックマークのAPI](http://developer.hatena.ne.jp/ja/documents/bookmark/apis/getinfo)を利用しようとするとクロスオリジン要求をブロックされqiitaのAPIと同じようにすることができません。

これはqiitaのAPIがJSONPとしてレスポンスを返すためクロスドメインにひっかからないのでしょうか？
仮にJSONPの場合制約にかからないのでしょうか？
その場合はてなブックマークのAPIでJSONPで返すにはどのようにすればよいでしょうか？
無知の質問が多く申し訳ありません。お力添えよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

#### はてなブックマークエントリー情報取得APIのJSONP対応

[質問に挙げられているAPI](http://developer.hatena.ne.jp/ja/documents/bookmark/apis/getinfo)に関してはJSONPでの取得方法が説明されています。

> また`http://b.hatena.ne.jp/entry/json/`に対し、以下のクエリーパラメータを GET
>   リクエストで送信することで、JSONP によるコールバック関数で囲まれたJSONデータを取得することができます。
>   (以下略)

JSONPの使い方が分からない場合はトライしてつまずいた所に絞って、また質問するとよいと思います。
下記は高速版(`/entry/jsonlite/`)でこのサイトのブックマークを取得する例です。

```html
<div><p>はてなブックマーク:</p>
    <pre id="hatena_bkm"></pre>
</div>

<script>
"use strict";

function my_hatena_bkm_callback(bkm_json){
    document.getElementById("hatena_bkm").textContent =
    JSON.stringify(bkm_json, undefined, 2);
}
</script>

<script src="http://b.hatena.ne.jp/entry/jsonlite/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fja.stackoverflow.com%2F&callback=my_hatena_bkm_callback"></script>
```

#### 「新着記事」取得のAPIがあるか

ただ、やりたいのは「新着記事のタグを収集」する事のようですね。
[はてなブックマークドキュメント一覧](http://developer.hatena.ne.jp/ja/documents/bookmark)をざっと見た限りでは、これを取得するAPIは無さそうですが、いかがでしょうか。
はてなが提供しているRSS(あるいはスクレイピングなど)と、APIを使い、自分でAPIを作るという手はあると思いますが、これは別の話になりますね。

Comment: mjy様
丁寧なご回答ありがとうございました。
現在やろうと考えていることの根本は現在のニュースサイトのように見出しが長々と出ているものではなく、リアルタイムで話題やニュースになっているタグを表示しその中で気になったタグを選択すればそのタグに関連するニュースが表示されるというものを作りたいなと思ったのが始まりです。
その手がかりとしてまずはてなブックマークの新着記事のタグを集めてみようと考えたのですが、どうやら行き詰ってしまったようです。
mjy様が回答してくださったプログラムを参考にはてなブックマークのページ自体の新着記事のページ( http://b.hatena.ne.jp/entrylist?sort=hot )とgoogleニュースから取り出してみようと思います。

Comment: 追記：追記：はてなブックマークAPIを使い新着記事のurlを利用しタグ収集を試みましたが、どうやら記事を表示しているだけではてなブックマークそのもののページからタグを収集することはできませんでした。
RSSにホットエントリーと新着記事を取得できるものがあるのですが、タグ情報が含まれておらずまた足止めをくらっております。

Answer (score 1):

JSONP は外部スクリプトとして読み込める形にした JSON のことで、通常の JSON とは形式が異なります。そのため API 提供側での対応が必要ですが、 Qiita も<del>はてなブックマークも</del>対応していません。

追記:はてなブックマークの当該APIは callback パラメータを付加することで JSONP で取得できるようです（[mjyさんの回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/19007/8000)参照）。

前述のデモサイトでの Qiita からのレスポンスには以下のヘッダが存在します。

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://bl.ocks.org
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000
```

これは [CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing)](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/HTTP_access_control#Simple_requests) で定められた、アクセス制御のために用いられるヘッダ群です。d3.js を含め Ajax 通信に用いられる XMLHttpRequest には [Same-Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) というルールが適用され、基本的に異なるオリジン間での通信は行えないのですが、これらのヘッダ群で許可されていた場合に限り通信が許可されます。ちゃんと `http://bl.ocks.org` が許可されていますね。

一方はてなブックマークのAPIではこれらのヘッダが出力されないため、「別オリジンからの要求を全て拒否した」ものとしてブラウザが解釈し、通信をブロックします。

その他参考記事など

- [HTTP access control (CORS) | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/HTTP_access_control)
- [CORS(Cross-Origin Resource Sharing)について整理してみた ｜ Developers.IO](http://dev.classmethod.jp/etc/about-cors/)
- [JavaScriptプログラミング講座【クロスオリジンリソースシェアリングについて（CORS）】](http://hakuhin.jp/js/resource_sharing.html)

Comment: 質問者が挙げている物を含め、はてなブックマークのAPIには、JSONPで取得出来る物があります。ただ、「新着記事」にはAPIが無さそうなので、その点ではおっしゃる通り「はてなブックマーク側で対応してもらえないと無理」みたいですね。

Comment: @mjy 確かに書いてありますね…見落としてました。

Comment: unarist様
なるほど,qiitaの方にはこのような記述が入っていたのですね。
ヘッダがあれば許可されることはなんとなく知っていたのですが、それを確認するところまで至りませんでした。
参考になりました、ありがとうございます。
mjy様が提示してくださっているJSONPを返す方法でどうにかならないか試行錯誤してみようと思います！ありがとうございました！

Answer (score 0):

[JSONProxy](https://jsonp.afeld.me/) や [allow-any-origin.appspot.com](http://allow-any-origin.appspot.com/) のようなクロスドメイン通信を可能にするサイトを一枚噛ませる方法があります。

```js
var url = "http://b.hatena.ne.jp/entry/json/http://www.hatena.ne.jp/";
var proxy_url = "http://allow-any-origin.appspot.com/" + encodeURIComponent(url);

d3.json(proxy_url, function(error, json) {
  if (error) {
    return console.warn(error);
  }
  $("#data").text(JSON.stringify({
    title: json.title,
    url:   json.url,
    count: json.count
  }));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<h1>はてなブックマーク</h1>
<pre id="data"></pre>
```

これらのサイトは基本的に無保証ですが、とりあえず動くものを作りたい場合には便利です。

必要に応じてAPIを返すページを自前で作って、あとから差し替えることもできます。

Comment: kosh様
こんなページがあったのですね、非常に驚きました...
この方法を用いて取得したjson形式のデータをそのままd3.jsに読み込ますことも可能なのでしょうか？

Comment: 上記のスニペットが動作しているなら、仕組み上はd3.jsでも動作するはずです。`d3.json("http://...", function() {...})` のURL部分を差し替えて試してみてください。

Comment: kosh様
上記のスニペットを試したところ正しく動作しました！
これが可能なのであれば試してみようと考え、現在はてなブックマークのRSS( http://feeds.feedburner.com/hatena/b/hotentry )をこちらの方法( http://blog.56doc.net/Entry/472/)を用いてjsonで読みとり、同じように要素を参照できるようできないのか考えてみたのですが、APIの機能的に指定をすればjsonの要素を返してくれるような設定がありません。
この場合jsonの中身にアクセスして取り出すことは難しいでしょうか？
イメージとしてはこのRSSに記述されている記事のタイトルとサムネイル、リンクを取得しそれをd3.jsに読み込ませたいです。わかりにくい書き方で申し訳ありません...

Comment: d3.jsにはxml形式のデータを読み込む関数も提供されています（`d3.xml`）。こちらを利用してみてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: あとこのサイトの特性上、コメント欄で応答を繰り返すよりも躓いた箇所を切り抜いて新規に質問しなおすことをオススメします。